# STL Map - When to use a custom comparator?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm using `std::map` to store to pointers to a class I use to wrap objects of different types. It's being used to represent a table from the Lua scripting language, as well as other Lua types. While I was making my table wrapper I realized `std::map` would be using the default comparator when storing my pointers in the tree. At first this seemed like a problem to me, but then I thought about it some more and decided it wouldn't be. Whatever the default comparison is, it shouldn't really matter (I think).

So, what I'm asking is this. Is it true that it doesn't really matter, and if so when would one want to use a custom comparator?

Comment: When comparison does not matter, use [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question lacks a bit of clarity. Let's assume you mean:

1. The *keys* in your std::map are pointers to a class. The *values* are something else unspecified.
2. Although you are using an ordered associative container, you don't really care what order the keys are stored in, since you will only be doing exact lookups.

In that case, comparing the pointers by address is fine. However, for this use case, you might want to use an `unordered_map` (aka hash table), officially available in C++11 but often available in c++ libraries even for C++03.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the ambiguity, your assumptions are indeed what I was thinking. I will be inserting a lot of data into the map and so a hash table probably isn't suitable, I'd rather have guaranteed logn behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

map stores and retrieves values based on weak equivalence of key. Say when you look for a key k1 in map m1 - (as map is implemented as balanced b-tree) the search would start from root node and proceed to left or right based on the value at the node is smaller than k1 or bigger than k1. And if both "value_at_node < k1" and "k1 < value_at_node" comparisons yield false then the map concludes that the key is found at the current node.

If key is pointer type then pointer values are compared by the default comparator. And weak equivalence of pointer values has the same result as strong equivalence ( = operator). If key comparison done on location of the key (address in memory) is not what you want but instead want comparison based on value at the address then one should use a custom comparator. For that matter any key type for which there is no < operator defined the map container cannot be used - there will be compiler error.

The comparator should agree well with weak equivalence rule - !(v < k) && !(k < v) is same as v == k. This should be rightly implemented and upheld by the customized comparator.